# Unity 3D - How to take/place a hole in a field?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm making a map customizing feature for my golf game, which users can drag and place obstacles to the golf course. Everything is prefab which I can easily drag/place. But I'm struggling with bunkers, they suppose to be holes in the ground with different physic behavior from the course.
Now when I place a bunker, it will be covered by the course.

Therefore I have to cut a hole in the mesh of the course which fit the bunker and I have to do this in runtime.
I tried several tool that help me do some boolean operations but the mesh will be broken after 2 or 3 holes.
Is there any tool that help me do this unlimited times without break the mesh? Or any better way to do this without cutting the mesh?

I tried some boolean operation tool but the result is not good at all.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljgwo.jpg)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO23O.png)